# Animate pattern to move vom left to right and back in Console

Tags: c#

I'm currently getting into c# and try to play around in the console.
I basically want to animate a logo in the console. I already wrote 2 methods to display the letters H and S with "#". Right now they're just written side by side. Now I want them to move from the left to the right and back. In the next  step I'd also like to make the letters bigger and smaller every few frames. They have the size 5x7 now, so it would change every frame like this:
3x5 -> 5x7 -> 7x9.

My idea would be to to write the letters, move one column to the right, delete the old lines and print a new one.

Any tips on what I could do from here?

```
public class Program
{
    static int row, col;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        WriteH();
        WriteS();
    }

    public static void WriteH()
    {
        for (row = 0; row < 7; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            {
                if ((col == 1 || col == 5) || (row == 3 && col > 1 && col < 6))
                {                       
                    Console.Write("#");                     
                }
                else
                {            
                    Console.Write(" ");                        
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteS()
    {
        for (row = 0; row < 7; row++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            {
                if (((row == 0 || row == 3 || row == 6) && col > 1 && col < 5)
                    || (col == 1 && (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 6))
                    || (col == 5 && (row == 0 || row == 4 || row == 5)))
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(col+7, row);
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(col+7, row);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting now. "Difficulties" is very vague. Please try to explain what you want to happen and what is actually happening in order for people to help.

Comment: I edited the post, so it's clear that I could use some hints on how to achieve the goal, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounters the same problem,I now figured out how to do it using an endless while loop. Scaling the letters should be possible in the same way. The commented part was my first while loop, but just moves from left to right.

```
    public class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //WriteH();
        //WriteS();
        MoveLetters();
    }


    /*public static void MoveLetters()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            WriteH(i);
            WriteS(i);
            i++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }*/


    public static void MoveLetters()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            for(i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                WriteH(i);
                WriteS(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            for(i=100; i>0; i--)
            {
                WriteH(i);
                WriteS(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void WriteH(int xPosition)
    {                            
            for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++)
            {
                for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++)
                {
                    if ((col == 1 || col == 5) || (row == 3 && col > 1  && col < 6))
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(col + xPosition, row);
                        Console.Write("#");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }             
    }
    public static void WriteS(int xPosition)
    {
        for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++)
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++)
            {
                if (((row == 0 || row == 3 || row == 6) && col > 1 && col < 5)
                    || (col == 1 && (row == 1 || row == 2 || row == 6))
                    || (col == 5 && (row == 0 || row == 4 || row == 5)))
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(col + 7 + xPosition, row);
                    Console.Write("#");
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

}
```